# Help with the graph of a unit step function

Tags: real-analysis

If I have $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}I(x - \frac{1}{n})$$
where f is the unit step function, what does the graph of f look like and where is it discontinuous?

---

My thinking:
If $x \leq 0$ then $f(x)$ will always evaluate to 0 since the unit step function will have a negative input $\forall n$. For $ x > 1$, we will always have $\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$, and for everything in between, we will get increasing smaller values of f(x) for a smaller x, but I can't tell if it's continuous or it's continuous or what it's really supposed to look like. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: May be [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xy2f70wobz) help. Notice that it's a rough approximation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $0 < x < 1$. There exists an integer $N(x)$ such that $x \geqslant  1/n$ for all $n \ge N(x)$. In fact, $N(x) = \lfloor 1/x \rfloor$. Thus for $0 < x < 1$,
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=N(x)}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
Divide $$(0, 1) = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k,$$

where $I_k = \left[\frac{1}{k+1}, \frac{1}{k}\right)$ and note that
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
on $I_k$. Therefore the discontinuities of $f(x)$ are at the points $x = 1/k$ for $k \ge 1$. They are jumps, so the graph of $f$ will look like a staircase, each step of length $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$.